# Adding Gmail API to android app

Tags: android, gmail, google-play-services, gmail-api

Since the Gmail API is not a part of the Google Play services SDK ([according to this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup)), but part of the Google Apps APIs, how do I make a Login using Gmail for an Android app?

I need access to user emails (read-only).

I have [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1) downloaded, but I am not sure of to how to use it.

Comment: You don't login with gmail, you authenticate with a google account (which can use [G+ signin](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)). When authenticating you specify the necessary scopes, which will allow you to access the user's email. Once you've authenticated you can then make calls to the methods in the client library. I suggest you follow the [QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java).

Comment: @Andy I can't add the necessary scopes as Android studio doesn't recognize Gmail as an API when making a new GoogleApiClient object. I tried the following to add the necessary scope but it doesn't help: `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Gmail.API)
                .addScope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY)
                .build();`